# receiving XML data via POST then displaying it

Tags: php, post, curl

I am having difficulties figuring this out. I can see I am posting XML and I see the length of it but I cannot figure out how to display or access the POST DATA

```
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml<br />
CONTENT-LENGTH: 640<br />
```

separately I have

```
curl -k -H 'content-type: text/xml' -d 'XML_DATA_HERE' https://ip/page.php
```

Comment: You may need to add some further details and clarify, its not entirely obvious what your issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php says:

> php://input allows you to read raw POST data. It is a less memory intensive alternative to $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and does not need any special php.ini directives. php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: correct i also found $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA after looking the above up